# Android Layout Editor missing

Tags: android

I tried to open my layout xml files in Eclipse now. And I only gets the error

```
No XML content. Please add a root view or layout to your document.
```

Wonder why this is a problem, my xml files are correct, E.G:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget32"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#e4e8ed">

    <Logic.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_finger"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to right click the .xml file, and open it with the `Android Layout Editor`, but I couldn't find this editor in my list. I also tried to add it from the Preferences menu, under the File Associations, but the editor is not showed here. The only android relatated xml editors are:

- Android Binary XML editor
- Android Common XML Editor
- Android Export    Editor
- Android Manifest Editor

Does anybody know why this happens? The layout editor has so many bugs, and I find it hard to use this tool if google doesn't update it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try updating android tools via SDK manager, I had this problem once, updating to latest version fixed that